# Select record not my friend

Tags: mysql

I have three MySQL tables:

`USERS` has columns `id` and `name`.

`POST` has columns `id`, `user_post`, `content`, and `date`

`SHARE` has columns `id`, `post_id`, and `tag_users`.

```
id        post_id           tag_users
1         2                 5,20
2         4                 12,21,9,16,4
3         5                 18,19
```

- variable $arraynotfriends contain string : '21','9','4','18','19','5','20'
- variable $arrayfriends contain string : '12','7','6'
- my friend is  id: 12,7,6

My query is:

```
select u.*,p.*,s.* from USERS u
left join POST p on (p.user_post = u.id)
left join SHARE s on (p.id = s.post_id)
where
u.id IN ('$arraynotfriends') = 0
```

and 1 record is 2

I want to get records 1 and 3 where not my friend is 12 in list

Answer (score 0):

should remove `=0` from statement `u.id IN ('$arraynotfriends') = 0` also should $arraynotfriends be a numeric array not string format

Comment: when I use NOT FIND_IN_SET(12, s.tag_friend_share) show exactly. But I want replace varriable $arrayfriends in position 12. How to do this.